# Redirecting www and non www to HTTPS on blogger

Tags: https, blogger, error

I have a blog on Blogger and have activated HTTPS. This link works:

```
https://www.example.com
```

But this does not:

```
https://example.com/
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: The "naked" name points to `184.168.131.241` where the `www` points to `74.125.21.121` and nothing seem to reply from `184.168.131.241` for a TLS (or event a TCP) handshake, hence the problem. Ask your hosting/DNS provider to set the DNS records according to your needs.

Comment: You can apparently set a redirect from the domain apex to the www subdomain in Blogger settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352219/using-naked-domain-with-blogger-com

Comment: @MrWhite Good find. Although a lot of services (at least the ones I use) don't support HTTPS when doing cross domain redirects. I don't know whether Blogger does or not.

Comment: Saw this, maybe it will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347183/force-non-www-and-https-via-htaccess

Comment: Just ensure that your domain nameservers are set rightly. Contact your domain name provider for help.